# For $f$ a continuous topological mapping, when are the values on the boundary of a set determined?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map between topological spaces, and suppose we know the value of $f$ on a subset $S\subset X$.

Continuity tells us that $f(\bar{S})\subset \overline{f(S)}$ for any $S\subset X$. But when does it prescribe the particular value of $f(x)$ for $x\in \bar{S}\setminus S$?

One sufficient criterion is 
$$
\text{$X$ is a first countable space and $Y$ is a Hausdorff space,}\tag{1} 
$$
since then given $x\in \bar{S}\setminus S$, we can choose $x_n\to x$ and I claim $f(x_n)$ must converge to a unique limit.

Is this the best we can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Theorem**.  Suppose $Y$ is Hausdorff and let $f,g : X \to Y$ be two continuous functions.  If $f=g$ on $S \subset X$, then $f=g$ on $\bar{S}$ (and in particular on $\partial S$).

You can prove this without filters or nets or sequences, it's a good exercise.  Here's a start: let $x \in \bar{S}$, and suppose to the contrary $f(x) \ne g(x)$.  Then there are disjoint open sets $U \ni f(x)$ and $V \ni g(x)$...

Without assuming something about $Y$ it is false.  For instance, if $Y$ has the indiscrete topology, every function from $X$ to $Y$ is continuous, and there's nothing stopping you from messing with its value on $\partial S$.

Answer (score 2):

You can omit the first countability. Only that $Y$ is Hausdorff is needed. If $X$ isn't first countable, you consider filters or nets for convergence, and for every $x\in \overline{S}$ there are filters on $S$/nets in $S$ that converge to $x$. The uniqueness of limits in Hausdorff spaces then determines $f(x)$.

Comment: What resource would you recommend for a good treatment of filters and nets? I know Munkres has only a short section on it. I had the impression they were outmoded, but if a question as simple as this may require them for the answer, sounds like they are somewhat important.

Comment: If you're doing anything much with spaces that aren't first countable, you _need_ to know at least one of the two fairly well. Better know both, for each is much more convenient to use in some situations than the other, and some authors prefer nets, others filters. For filters, I suppose Bourbaki treats them fairly well (but I have to admit I haven't read Top. Gén.), I learned them from an out-of-print German book, so that will probably not help you. For nets, Pedersen's "Analysis Now" contains a not bad treatment.

Comment: I guess I would like to ask the converse: if one is working with first countable spaces, should one know filters/nets?

Comment: It's always good to know more, but if you're only dealing with situations where sequences suffice, it's no must to know filters and/or nets. But, chances are, one does deal with spaces that are not first countable at some time.

Comment: Where do these show up in applications? Non-metrizable function spaces?

Comment: Such, and the weak and weak* topologies on topological vector spaces are common examples.